# React JS how to fix cannot add property updater, object is not extensible, when using 'This'

Tags: reactjs

I am using a 'this.state' variable to hold a bool, until a function is triggred, this has been working fine with my websites up until now.

my constructer, and the function to trigger the error will be left below as well as the line with the error.

The error is being triggered on all the classes that use the same code,

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          email: '', 
          password: '',
          toDashboard: false,
        };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }



//see update for new handleLogin() function

render() {
      if (this.state.toDashboard === true) {
        return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
      }
}
```

This is how invoke handleLogin():

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = {
         password: this.state.password,
         email: this.state.email
        }
        this.handleLogin(form)
    }
```

update: I have change my function to an arrow function like this and are still getting the same error:

```
 handleLogin = (form) => {
      const email = form['email']
      const password = form['password']
      fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
          var errorMessage = error.message
          console.log(errorMessage)
      });
      fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
          if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            //error happens here
            this.setState({ toDashboard: true })
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
          }
      });          
  }
```

error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property updater, object is not extensible
    at adoptClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12821)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12882)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17100)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22157)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12639)
    at LoginForm.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:471)
    at loginform.js:31
    at auth.esm.js:389
```

GitHub repo is here if you want to see all the files: https://github.com/lukeacko12/tikkr

Comment: Why do you need `thisClone = this` ?

Comment: as i get another error if i dont, 
```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined```, that happens if i dont use ```this clone = this```

Comment: you can use arrow functions, so you won't need save `this` in local var

Comment: still getting. the sane error doing that @ИльяСавич

Comment: please provide how do you invoke `handleLogin` @LukeAcko13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here handleLogin is not binded with this, you have 2 lines in constructor

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

I can't see those two functions, so replace them with, or just add (if they exist), this one

```
this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
```

or I would use an arrow function, and forget about binding

```
handleLogin = form => {
        const email = form['email']
        const password = form['password']
        fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
            var errorMessage = error.message
            console.log(errorMessage)
        });
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
            if (user) {
              console.log(user)
             this.setState({ toDashboard: true })

              console.log(this.state.toDashboard)
            } else {
              // No user is signed in.
            }
        });          
    }
```

Comment: Im getting this error now following your code: ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot add property updater, object is not extensible```

Comment: where is this error thrown ? inside handle login ? pls if you could send the stack trace

Comment: i have put the error on the question and it is thrown where the //error here comment is.